# Display images stored in AWS S3 on website with php

Tags: php, web, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, photo

I'm building a MYSQL database driven website on a AWS EC2 instance.  Users can submit their data and we will automatically create a web page for them.  The webpage will display their submitted data including a photo.  Upon original submission of the user's data, we store the photo in S3 using AWSSDKforPHP.  When their information is approved by an administrator a webpage is created via a php script.

I've tried the method of generating a signed url.  This however requires a expiration time.  Is there a way around this?  It also includes your access and secret key in the request.  Not sure if that is the most secure way to do things.  I'd like the method to be as secure as possible so I don't want to make the bucket public.  Unless there is a way to make the stored images available only for viewing.

What's the best method to use in a situation like this?  Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically URLs to amazon S3 buckets are s3.amazonaws/bucket_name/key_name all you need to do is make sure the content on those buckets is publicly available and that mime type for those keys is indeed image (image/jpeg or image/png)

Comment: If I make the bucket public won't that allow people to delete images and mess with the data?

Comment: They'll need write permission and your API keys to do that :)

Answer (score -1):

I used [this web tool](https://www.backand.com/) to manage my site. I opend my bucket just to its ip  and now i can  control the restriction from the tool, for  the basic viewer I gave read access only